# Perfect Matching for Edge-transitive Hypergraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergraph, perfect-matchings

I'm new to this subject, but I've noticed that a lot of work has been done on perfect matching in k-uniform hypergraphs. I'm curious to know if there are any results on perfect matching in the more specific case of edge-transitive hypergraphs.